# Resend communities confirmation email

Tags: community

Is there a way in Salesforce communities that I can resend a confirmation email to a user?

Basically, we have a page that will make a community user for an existing contact. Once it makes it for them, it will send out a confirmation email. If for whatever reason the person doesn't get the email, is there anyway we can have a 'Resend email' button?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is quite old now, but I wanted to put this here in case it helps someone in the future.

I verified that toggling the active state of the community via community work spaces will send a welcome email to any users that were added to the community but have not yet received a welcome email ie. welcome emails were disabled when initially adding the member.

If a welcome email has been sent at some point in the past it doesn't look like this option or the permission set option in Mohith's answer works. You would need to utilize the reset password workaround.

Answer (score 3):

A potential workaround for this is as follows. Find all those users that have no logged in (i.e. LastLoginDate = null) and move their profile to another which is not in the community. Then swap them back to the profile in the community and the Welcome Email should be sent back out.

Comment: This is a perfect answer and fits our requirements exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see the welcome emails are sent only on community activation or whenever you add the members to the community .

If users do not get emails ,then i would suggest you to create a permission set consisting of the members you want to resend the email and add the permission set to the members in set up .Adding permission set will imply adding members and should trigger welcome email again .(NOTE:: I have not tested yet but theoretically it should just work )

[image]

Comment: I was afraid there'd be no automatic way to do it. I'm not sure that solution will meet our needs exactly, but I'll look into it. Might be better to have than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Try in sandbox first ..

Answer (score 1):

So, basically what I ended up doing was utilizing the 'Forgot Password' functionality. The email template will end up being different, but the end results is pretty much what we want.

After you click the button to create your account, a link will appear in case you didn't receive the email for some reason. You click the link, and it runs the forgotPassword function which sends you an email to the community with a link that will bring you to the password entry screen.

Answer (score 0):

Inactivate user first. And then Activate user in another transaction. In this way, Salesforce will resend welcome email to this user.

When user is updated as inactive, user is moved out from community. When user is set as active, user is added into community. When user is added into a commuunity, a welcome email is sent.

Benefit of this solution is that no extra user profile is required.