# How to track Digital Experience invitations?

Tags: community, user, customer-portal, user-management, digital-experience

I'm working on some user interface to track whether users accept an invitation (a welcome email with a link) to a Digital Experience or not, and to present an option to re-send the invitation. [Resend communities confirmation email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111704/resend-communities-confirmation-email) is helpful for that.

But as the re-invitation can be initiated e.g. by the site being activated or directly from the User record as well as from my user interface, I'm looking for a reliable way to track the datetime of all invitations (e.g. via a trigger). Is there a way to do that?

(Might be possible to spot the emails that are sent via a trigger on `EmailMessage` but would be great if there was some more specific object/field to look at. Though from a quick test, an `EmailMessage` record is not created for an invite so no help.)

A related problem is that when a user clicks on the welcome email link, a row is created in the `LoginHistory` table with a status of "Success" immediately before they are prompted to change their password (and the corresponding `User.LastLogin` is set too). No obvious way to check for this in between state.